# How to add nav bar on top of Image with white background

Tags: html, css

I am adding nav bar on top of image. Nav bar has white background with logo pic left side and other content on right side. But looks like nav bar is not taking 100% width. If I increase width it is not  woking. I added all bootstrap link to make it responsive.

```css
.main{
      position: relative;
        
    }
    .topNav{
        position: absolute;
       width:100%;
       
    }
    
    li{
        float: left;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: aliceblue;
        height: 100px;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    .topImg{
        position: absolute;
        top:100px;
    }
    .logo{
        float: left;
    }   
}

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="main text-center">
                 <div class="topNav">
                    <ul>
                         <li class="logo"><img src="https://i2.wp.com/riverviewramslacrosse.com/wp-content/uploads/img-header-logo.png?fit=204%2C202"></li>
                         <li> Home</li>
                         <li>About</li>
                         <li> Contact</li>
                         <li> Apply</li>   
                  </ul>
                </div>
                
                <div class="topImg text-center">
                    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454165804606-c3d57bc86b40?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" class="img-responsive img-center image-fluid" alt="officeImg">
                </div>
           
            </div>
       
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>``    
    
</body>
```

Comment: I am trying do add nab bar on top of image with white background . I added two dives in main div container which contain top nav div and other is topImg div.

Comment: I want to  position them(nav bar and img ) on top of each other. Image should be in the horizontally center and nav bar should take width same as image.  Also Logo left side and other list items right side.

Comment: The reason you could be having problems is because you are trying to make changes to your css while you are running bootstrap. The whole point of using bootstrap is to not have to worry as much about CSS files, I would refer to the bootstrap documentation for more information. Here is the link to their section on navbars: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/